# How to get "%systemroot%" directory using ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3

I want run "%systemroot%\System32\reg.exe" this file to do something, but when I use "new File("%systemroot%\System32\reg.exe");" the ActionScript cannot find file, so anyone can help me find this?

Comment: Are you trying to run this from an Air app, in-browser Flash Player, or standalone Flash Player?

Comment: Hi, Anon, I want to run this from an Air app........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since AIR is multi-platform and %systemroot% works only on Windows, it's not possible.
But you can make a *.bat that installs with your application.

```
echo %systemroot% > systemroot.txt
```

So, you have to execute that *.bat file one time, when you install the application.
Then, you just open the systemroot.txt, read the first line, and you have what you asked for.

I hope it helps.

(Maybe not for you because this thread is so old, but for anyone that ends here searching a solution)